# How to retrieve data from a multi level object in Ionic 3?

Tags: arrays, angular, for-loop, ionic-framework, ngfor

This page works likes the following. The user selects a product (C2, Coca Cola, etc.) then the prices from the different supermarket are supposed to be displayed. This is the object I created.

```
productPrices = [
    {
        name: "C2 Green Tea",
        prices: [
            {
                smPrice: 19.15,
                tsPrice: 19.25,
                rbPrice: 19.10
            }
        ],
        stock: 50
    },
    {
        name: "Coca Cola",
        prices: [
            {
                smPrice: 21.50,
                tsPrice: 21.45,
                rbPrice: 24.50
            }
        ],
        stock: 50
    },
    {
        name: "Nature's Spring",
        prices: [
            {
                smPrice: 12.50,
                tsPrice: 11.50,
                rbPrice: 13.00
            }
        ],
        stock: 50
    },
    {
        name: "Red Horse Beer",
        prices: [
            {
                smPrice: 31.50,
                tsPrice: 29.50,
                rbPrice: 30.90
            }
        ],
        stock: 50
    },
];

getProductPrice(product: string){
     return this.productPrices.filter(item => item.name == product);
 }
```

By using the `getProducPrice()` method, I'm able to get the product selected and its properties. But I can't get the value of the prices. What I have on the template page is this.

```
<div *ngFor="let itemPrice of productPrices">
  <div *ngFor="let marketPrice of itemPrice.prices">

       <form (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(userForm)" #userForm="ngForm" >
        <ion-list>
            <ion-list-header>
              Supermarkets
            </ion-list-header>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                <img src="assets/grocery/market-logo/ts.jpg">
              </ion-thumbnail>
              <p>{{marketPrice.tsPrice}}</p>
              <button ion-button clear item-end (click)="onBuy()" >Buy</button>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                <img src="assets/grocery/market-logo/sm.png">
              </ion-thumbnail>
              <p>{{marketPrice.smPrice}}</p>
              <button ion-button clear item-end (click)="onBuy()"> Buy</button>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                <img src="assets/grocery/market-logo/rb.jpg">
              </ion-thumbnail>
              &#8369;<input name="price" value="{{marketPrice.rbPrice}}">
               <p>{{marketPrice.rbPrice}}</p> 
              <button ion-button clear item-end (click)="onBuy()">Buy</button>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label>Enter Quantity</ion-label>
              <ion-input type="number" min="0"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </form>  

  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with that is that if I use a form to submit, it'll submit all the values including the prices of the other supermarkets. 
Is there a better way for me to loop from the object I received and access the prices values of each product? I'm not using a DB nor is this file saved in a json file. I just want to know if there's a better way to get values at the typescript file by using some methods. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this you will property of selected product

```
<div *ngFor="let item of productPrices"> 

    <button (click) ="getProductPrice(item)">get</button>

</div>
```

In your ts file

```
 getProductPrice(product: any){
        console.log(product);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used your answer to make it work by passing data here and there. This is my first app I'm building and I don't have that much experience in object handling. Thanks again!

Comment: @YoelLorenzo then upvote and accept my answer if it had helped